# How to Convert a Class Component to a Functional Component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I had never used React Class Components And Want to shoot confetti when some event happened. I'm confused with  Class Component. Hope You can help with this issue.  tried by creating arrow functions and removing this keyword .But I can't understand how to transform getInstance() function even why it is there?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCanvasConfetti from 'react-canvas-confetti';

export default class Confetti extends Component {
    getInstance = (instance) => {
        // saving the instance to an internal property
        this.confetti = instance;
    }

    onClickDefault = () => {
        // starting the animation
        this.confetti();
    }

    onClickCustom = () => {
        // starting the animation with custom settings
        this.confetti({ particleCount: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000), spread: 180 });
    }

    onClickCallback = () => {
        // calling console.log after the animation ends
        this.confetti().then(() => {
            console.log('do something after animation');
        });
    }

    onClickReset = () => {
        // cleaning the canvas
        this.confetti.reset();
    }

    render() {
        const style = {
            position: 'fixed',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            zIndex: -1

        };
        const stylediv = {
            position: 'fixed',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            zIndex: 300000

        };

        return (
            <>
                <div style={stylediv}>

                    <ReactCanvasConfetti
                        // set the styles as for a usual react component
                        style={style}
                        // set the class name as for a usual react component
                        className={'yourClassName'}
                        // set the callback for getting instance. The callback will be called after initialization ReactCanvasConfetti component
                        refConfetti={this.getInstance}
                    />

                    <button onClick={this.onClickDefault}>Fire with default</button>
                    <button onClick={this.onClickCustom}>Fire with custom</button>
                    <button onClick={this.onClickCallback}>Fire with callback</button>
                    <button onClick={this.onClickReset}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create Functional Component of the above Class Component

Comment: `getInstance` is a [Callback Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactCanvasConfetti from 'react-canvas-confetti';

const Confetti = () => {
    const Ref = useRef()
    const getInstance = (instance) => {
      if (Ref.current) {
         Ref.current.confetti = instance
      }
   }
   const onClickDefault = () => {
      Ref.current.confetti();
   }
   const onClickCustom = () => {
      Ref.current.confetti({ particleCount: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000), 
      spread: 180 });
   }

   const onClickCallback = () => {
      Ref.current.confetti().then(() => {
          console.log('do something after animation');
      });
   }
   const onClickReset = () => {
      Ref.current.confetti.reset();
   }

   const style = {
    position: 'fixed',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: -1
  };
  const stylediv = {
    position: 'fixed',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 300000

  };
  return (
    <>
        <div ref={Ref} style={stylediv}>

            <ReactCanvasConfetti
                style={style}
                className={'yourClassName'}
                refConfetti={getInstance}
            />
            <button onClick={onClickDefault}>Fire with default</button>
            <button onClick={onClickCustom}>Fire with custom</button>
            <button onClick={onClickCallback}>Fire with callback</button>
            <button onClick={onClickReset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}
export default Confetti